exit the cronjob run if shell script is already executing
I have a cronjob scheduled for shell script to run every 10min,
00,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * /u01/app/1.sh
if for some reason 10th minute 1.sh script is running more than 10mins then 20th runtime should exit with some status, any suggestions plz:
#!/bin/bash

ps_out=`ps -ef | grep  1.sh | grep -v 'grep'`

result=$(echo $ps_out | grep "$1")

if [[ "$result" != "" ]];then

    exit 100

else

my code of script

fi

in this case, my present/first run itself failing.
Any suggestions plz.

Use flock or save the PID + StartTime somewhere so you can check if the previous job is still running

Please read the description of the "shell" tag. You can [edit] your question to fix that and then also add a "cron" tag.
